# C++ Undefined reference to functions

Tags: c++, reference, undefined, codeblocks

I hope you will help me.
So,I have this class and whenever I try to compile the main.cpp I get the errors: Undefined reference to 'Sally::Sally()', to 'void Sally::print()' and twice for 'Sally::~Sally()'

***here is my header file:***

```
#ifndef SALLY_H
#define SALLY_H


class Sally
{
    public:
        Sally();
        void print();
        virtual ~Sally();
    protected:
    private:
};

#endif // SALLY_H
```

***here is my Sally.cpp file***

```
#include<iostream>
#include "Sally.h"
using namespace std;

Sally::Sally()
{

}
void Sally::print()
{
  cout<<"print something"<<endl;
}

Sally::~Sally()
{

}
```

**here is my main.cpp file**

```
#include <iostream>
#include"Sally.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Sally salObj;
    salObj.print();
```

}

I saw a comment here that I should include the 3 files in a project but whenever I do I make a Console Application and it prints out "Hello world" even though I don't even have that anywhere. I'd love if someone can help me,I've been bugged with this for a couple of days and nothing seems to make it better.

Comment: What compiler are you using? you need to link Sally.cpp

Comment: Very hard to help with this from a distance. The problem is not the code, it's your understanding of Code::Blocks. Try and find someone who can sit down with you and show you what you are doing wrong. BTW you do need to create a project and add all your files to it, but obviously you are doing that wrong somehow.

Answer (score 3):

Code::Blocks adds a default `main.cpp` file to a *Console Application* project. You need to remove that file, and add your own files by right clicking on the project name -> "Add files...". Make sure that you add all three files.

[image: Remove main.cpp]
[image: Add your files]

Comment: @user2851616: I'm glad I could have helped! Please accept the answer if it answers your question. Thanks!